# global variable update not triggering if/else statement in jquery

Tags: jquery, if-statement

See the example below, basically I want it to execute if on the first click, and then for all subsequent clicks to execute the else statement but even though the variable is updating it isn't switching to else e.g if the alert message is saying the variable is now at three it still doesn't go to else. I'm guessing it's a scope issue but how do I get around it - can anyone advise?

```
var loaded = 0;

if (loaded == 0) {
$('body').on('click', '#button', function(){
alert(loaded);
loaded += 1;
});

} else {
alert(loaded + 'yay its not 0');
};
```

Comment: The if statement only runs once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your if condition only runs one time. Try placing your check within the click event:

```
var loaded = 0;
$('body').on('click', '#button', function () {
    if (loaded == 0) {
        alert(loaded);
        loaded += 1;
    } else {
        alert(loaded + 'yay its not 0');
    };
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/5Xgf9/)**

Comment: I was just about to post this up as an answer to my own question but you beat me to it :)

Answer (score 1):

This should hopefully behave as intended:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var clicked = false;
    $('body').click(function() { 
        if(clicked) {
            alert("Already clicked");
        } else {
            alert("Not clicked yet");
            clicked = true;
        }
    });
});
```

Hope that helped.

Answer (score 0):

Events dont work like that once its assigned it always runs unless you use `.one` or manually call `.off` after the fact - but even then your check will only get executed once when the script loads, not when a click happens. You need to handle the if/else inside your event handler.

```
var loaded = 0;
$('body').on('click', '#button', function(){
   if(loaded === 0) {
      alert(loaded);
      loaded += 1;
   } else {

   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Put your check inside the click handler:

```
  $('body').on('click', '#button', function(){
      if(loaded == 0){
          alert(loaded);
          loaded += 1;
      }
      else{
         alert(loaded + 'yay its not 0');

      }
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

The `if` statement is only executed the first time, after that you enter the `on()` method and bind the function to `#button`, but there's no other evaluation afterwards, in this case it'd only go to the `else` part if `loaded`'s initial value wasn't 0, so you should change your code to:

```
$('body').on('click', '#button', function(){
if (loaded == 0) {
  alert(loaded);
loaded += 1;
  } else {
alert(loaded + 'yay its not 0');
  }
});
```